# Automation Spotify Login using Selenium, Python

Tags: python, selenium, spotify

I have a Voice Assistant. And I want it to Login to my Spotify Account and play a song.
The real problem is there are no IDs for buttons. So I am having trouble locating buttons and clicking them.

```
elif 'spotify' in query:
        def spotify_login():
            DRIVER = webdriver.Chrome(
                executable_path='<EXECUTABLE_PATH>')
            print('Searching for Login Button')
            DRIVER.get('https://open.spotify.com/')
            speak("Opened Spotify.")
            DRIVER.maximize_window()
            login_button = DRIVER.find_element_by_id('<id>')
            login_button.click()
            speak('Clicked On Login')

        spotify_login()
```

Here is the code.

Comment: Have you tried locating them by XPATH?

Comment: @ejmin I tried XPath... it didn't work. But when I tried Full XPath... it worked like a charm.
Thanks for reaching out to me and helping me out. :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried automation through a dedicated spotify api such as "tekore" or "Spotipy":
https://pypi.org/project/tekore/

https://github.com/plamere/spotipy

It might be easier to use either of these apis to interact with the Spotify web app rather than trying to automate the process with selenium.

Comment: I can confirm that the Spotify API is indeed capable of logging users in and playing back songs.

Answer (score -1):

login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='login-button']"))
)

## Click on the login button

login_button.click()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).